# How can I use `-i` option from ssh-keygen?

Tags: ssh, openssl, ssh-keygen

I was trying to get a public key in Openssh format from an existing .p12 certificate. I can see little to no documentation on this.

I saw this option `-i` option in `ssh-keygen` man page. That sounds similar to what I want to achieve. i.e., change one format of key to OpenSSH format.

I tried multiple examples, but I always get `format not supported error`. What are possible interchangeable formats?

It would be great to get an example how `-i` format works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [su] or [unix.se]. When you do, you should showing exactly how you're running `ssh-keygen` and exactly what error you're getting. Don't paraphrase the error. It would also be helpful to show what format input file you have.

Comment: The formats are in [same man page under -m](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#m): RFC4716 PKCS8 PEM. The description there has some flaws but it is correct about one thing: OpenSSH does not support PKCS12. I don't see how it would help to have examples of something that cannot achieve your goal. If you have or get OpenSSL (an entirely different thing), you could use that with `ssh-keygen -y` (not `-i`) to do what you want, but that's (now) offtopic in addition to being prohibited by your question. @Kenster: .p12 strongly implies PKCS12 format.